# "He told me he had seen Charlie the day before" -- What's its direct speech?

Tags: reported-speech

How can I change these sentences to direct speech?

> He told me he had seen Charlie the day before.
>   He said you wanted to have lunch with him the following day.

Comment: The most likely versions are probably *He said "I saw Charlie yesterday"* and *He said "Axia wants to have lunch with me tomorrow"*. But there's quite a lot of potential ambiguity involved - your first example could be a perfectly valid way of converting something like *The day before, he said "I have seen Charlie"* to direct speech. The second case is even more ambiguous (we don't know whether ***him*** refers to the speaker or to some other third party, as well as not knowing whether *the following day* refers to time of lunching or speaking).

Comment: He said, "I saw Charlie yesterday". He said to you,  " You want to have lunch with me tomorrow".

Answer (score 3):

- > He said, "I saw Charlie yesterday".
- > He said, "He/She wants to have lunch with me tomorrow".

He/she refers to the participant who gets it told. *The day before* turns to *yesterday*, and *the following day* turns to *tomorrow*. Tenses are shifted one step towards future tense because of past tense in *he said*.